# Anyone know why this :after CSS isn't working in IE9?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, pseudo-element

[This submit button](http://jsfiddle.net/BWC9q/6/) should be rounded on the left side, and pointed on the right side. It's working in non-ie browsers, but in IE9, it is not working.

If I look at the styles in the developer tools, the .flat-button:after rule has everything crossed out, as if it is superseded by something. What?

```
<button type="submit" class="flat-button">Submit</button>
<style>
.flat-button {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border: none;
    padding: 0 12px;
    margin: 0 3px 3px 0;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
    font-family:'Trebuchet MS', Arial, helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-collapse: separate;
    height: 26px;
    line-height: 26px;
    background: #5191cd;
}
.flat-button:hover {
    background: #1c3f95;
}
.flat-button:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: ' ';
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    left: 100%;
    border: 13px solid transparent;
    border-left-color: #5191cd;
}
.flat-button:hover:after {
    border-left-color: #1c3f95;
}
</style>
```

Comment: It works if you change `<button>` into `<a>`, so it's something to do with `button`..

Comment: In support of @thirtydot's suggestion, yes, [using a `a` instead of `button` seems to work](http://jsfiddle.net/BWC9q/7/). BoltClock may or may not agree.

Comment: That is good to know, but I would like to be able to use it for form submission without javascript. Or is there a way to do that with anchors somehow?

Comment: Chris, to answer your question, you can submit a form on clicking a link using JS. I know why you'd rather use a button, but IE has problems with button support. I don't know a good workaround other than using JS to paper over that particularly flaw. See http://jsfiddle.net/BWC9q/8/ for something close, but not quite.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After playing around for a while, I found a simple fix for IE9.

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/BWC9q/10/

All you have to is add `overflow: visible` to `.flat-button`.

Comment: Good job thirtydot; how did you figure that out?

Comment: I just kept trying stuff. Eventually I saw that the `button` seemed to have `overflow: hidden`, so then I tried `overflow: visible` and it worked.

Comment: Very cool; amazing how the spaghetti method can work. I didn't get there.

Comment: thirtydot, when someone asks if you are a god, you say "YES"!

Comment: in my case it didn't work if there is no background set. So setting bacground to rgba(0,0,0,0) was required.