# IE8 and IE9 :before and :after elements position absolute are hidden

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, css-position, pseudo-element

I am trying to create a button with "caps" on either end, and a repeating background, in order to keep the button a flexible size.

In order to do this, I have used the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements in CSS, along with `position:absolute` to get it outside of the main button's background-covered space (using negative values).

It works in FF and Chrome, but it looks like in IE8 and 9, the images are there, but are "outside" the button, and therefore are hidden.  Does anyone know how to pop these pseudo-elements "out" of the button, so that they will render?

I want to keep the HTML to *just* the `<button></button>` element, and am using SASS.
You can see a jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Dqr76/8/ or the code below:

```
button {
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
    border:0;
    background-image: url(../images/btn_bg.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 22px;
    line-height: 22px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 5px;
    vertical-align: top;

    &:before {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 22px;
        background-image: url(../images/btn_left.png);
        width: 5px;
        position: absolute;
        left: -5px;
        top: 0;
        content: "";
    }

    &:after {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 22px;
        background-image: url(../images/btn_right.png);
        width: 5px;
        position: absolute;
        right: -5px;
        top: 0;
        content: "";
    }
}
```

*Just a sidenote, before someone brings it up, I know that these pseudo-elements do not work in < IE8, and have created a work-around that is not effecting this problem.*

Comment: Did you know [jsfiddle also understands scss](http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/Dqr76/)? (please complete my jsfiddle example so people can mess arround with the code)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I updated it with some dummy images and added a link above

Comment: We still need the new url that jsfiddle generated :p

Comment: You say you know IE7 and below don't know pseudo-elements, yet your CSS for these elements includes a bunch of hacks for IE7 (*display:inline,zooms). You could remove those for added cleanliness.

Comment: I removed them - thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add `overflow: visible;` to the button element, and it shows up.
Demonstrated at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dqr76/9/)

I swear I tried that already, but I guess not.  [Thanks to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560138/anyone-know-why-this-after-css-isnt-working-in-ie9?rq=1)

Comment: Solving your own question, like a boss. :) +1