# IE8 absolute positioned elements within button element are wrong

Tags: button, internet-explorer-8, css-position

Title says it all: absolute positioned children of a button element are wrong in IE8
Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sjeiti/paFKM/)
And here's the mandatory piece of code:

```
<button><div></div></button>
<style>
button{
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 0;
    background: gray;
}
button div{
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
}​
</style>
```

I've searched and tried everything I could think of. Maybe I should abandon using the button element :-/

What's going on here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [IE8 and IE9 :before and :after elements position absolute are hidden](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11164634/ie8-and-ie9-before-and-after-elements-position-absolute-are-hidden). TL;DR, use `overflow:visible;` on the button element: http://jsfiddle.net/paFKM/2/

Comment: Adding `overflow:visible` to the button does indeed fix this problem!

Comment: `Maybe I should abandon using the button element`. You should not abandon using it, but you should not put a div (= block element) inside a button (= inline element). That is asking for trouble, and it makes the code invalid.

Comment: I am almost sure that you are not allowed to put a div element, which is a block type element, within a button element, which I believe is an inline element. This kind of imbrication might cause some compatibility issues to some browsers, especially the older ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an overflow:visible to the button css.

Here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/innerurge1/os2e9c2j/7/. Also you should swap out the divs with spans as this is more semantic. Divs are not "allowed" in buttons, because they are block elements and buttons are inline.

```
.parent{
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 0;
    background: gray;
    text-align : left;
    overflow:visible;
}
```