# Div inside button not working as expected in IE

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I want to position an absolute `<div>` element inside a `<button>`, the element needs to be slightly out of the button bounds, as follows:

*HTML:*

```
<button class="container">
  <div class="child">child</div>
</button>
```

*CSS:*

```
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1rem;
  left: 1rem;
}
```

This works exactly as I expect in Chrome, but in IE the child doesn't **get out of the button boundaries**, This is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/urfasqkg/).

*Chrome:*

[image: chrome]

*IE*

[image: IE]

Tested in IE 11 and Chrome 51.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `overflow: visible;` to the button element.

Duplicate of:

[IE8 and IE9 :before and :after elements position absolute are hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11164634/ie8-and-ie9-before-and-after-elements-position-absolute-are-hidden)

[IE8 absolute positioned elements within button element are wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14129550/ie8-absolute-positioned-elements-within-button-element-are-wrong)