# Make a universal loading icon for buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create some type of "universal" loading indicator that'll appear next to a button that's clicked. For example; I have a page that has two buttons, one for a contact form and the other for a subscription form. My first thought was to create a custom div next to each button via jQuery. But, I'm trying to avoid erroneous div's on my page.

The code I'm trying to use makes the loading indicator appear inside the button rather than outside. Here's the code with a link to JSFiddle:

[JSFIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/FHmqF/1/)

CSS

```
#contact, #subscribe {
    margin:50px;
    width:100px;
    height:25px;
}
.indicator {
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    top:-23px;
    right:-25px;
    width:16px;
    height:16px;background:url(../graphics/loader.gif) no-repeat;
}
```

jQuery

```
$('#contact-submit').click(function()
{   
    $(this).addClass('indicator');
});
$('#subscribe-submit').click(function()
{   
    $(this).addClass('indicator');
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="contact">
    <button id="contact-submit">Contact</button>                                            
</div>  
<div id="subscribe">
    <button id="subscribe-submit">Subscribe</button>                                            
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can make use of pseudo-element `:after`? Example:

```
.indicator {
    position: relative;
}
.indicator:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 3px;
    margin-top: -8px;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background:url(http://www.graphicsoptimization.com/blog/wp-includes/images/go_examples/2008_05/indicator.gif) no-repeat;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FHmqF/3/

*Disclaimer: This approach will not work on `<input type="button">` buttons as these elements can't have inner content.*

Comment: Wow, this works just like I want! What exactly is `:after` doing? and what browsers are compatible with this? Thank you for your help :)

Comment: `:after` and `:before` are used for generated content. They are supported by all major browsers (IE8+) http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent.

Comment: Thank you for the disclaimer, very good information. This will help me on my approach in making my very own Twitter Bootstrap CSS styles ;)

Comment: Glad to help. If you need to support IE7, you can simply write additional CSS rule (IE7 hack) with simple background image instead of fancy `:after` background.

Comment: Also, I gave the `right:` a negative value to make it appear outside of the button.

Comment: One last question, how would remove the indicator after the server callback was successful?

Comment: To add indicator: `$('#btn').addClass('indicator')`.
To remove it: `$('#btn').removeClass('indicator')`. http://jsfiddle.net/FHmqF/4/

Comment: I'll have to play with that, for some reason it's not removing the loader. Also, I tried this is IE and it doesn't load the indicator at all, hmm. Damn IE, lol.

Comment: Try to add `overflow: visible` as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560138/anyone-know-why-this-after-css-isnt-working-in-ie9)

Comment: I added `overflow: visible` to the button and it works like a champ :) I just have to play around with `$(this).removeClass('indicator');` because it's not removing the class. It might be because it's in a $.post(), but I'll read up on it, thanks again.

Comment: Note that inside `$.post()` success function `this` will no longer refer to your button, that's why it doesn't work. Try this: `var $self = $(this); $.post(url, function() { $self.removeClass('indicator') })`.

Comment: Figured it out, since it was inside the `$.post()` I used `$('#subscribe-submite').removeClass('indicator')` instead of   `$(this).removeClass('indicator')` and it works like a champ, WOOT!

Answer (score 0):

Like Mike already pointed out you're attaching the class to the button itself, try something like this and play around with the css, or tell me where exactly you want to have your indicator.

```
$('#contact-submit').click(function()
{   
    $('<div class="indicator"></div>').appendTo($(this).parent());
});
$('#subscribe-submit').click(function() 
{   
    $('<div class="indicator"></div>').appendTo($(this).parent());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ls3LW/