# pseudo-selector :before not positioning correctly in IE9,10

Tags: css, internet-explorer, position, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10

I've encountered a problem that eludes me. I have an absolutely positioned pseudo-selector `:before` inside of a relatively positioned container that is positioned correctly in everything but IE9 and 10.

I've spent some time researching the problem and tried to implement [thirtydot's solution mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560138/anyone-know-why-this-after-css-isnt-working-in-ie9).

Here's a sample of the code: http://jsfiddle.net/66d25/20/

In all other browsers, the quotes appear correctly in the top left corner of the containing blockquote paragraph. In IE9/10 the quotes are improperly positioned in the middle top of the quote bubble.

I tried to add `overflow:visible` to the containing p tag but that didn't fix the problem. I have also included my scss below. Any insights into this problem would be greatly appreciated.

```
    blockquote {
        border-left: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 2em 0 1em 0;
        position: relative;
        &:after, &:before {
            top: 100%;
            border: solid transparent;
            content: '';
            height: 0;
            width: 0;
            position: absolute;
            pointer-events: none;
            display:block;
        }
        p {
            color: shade($charcoal, 20%);
            margin: 0;
            background: #fff;
            @include border-radius(5px);
            @include box-shadow(inset 0 2px 0 rgba(70, 130, 180, 0.7), -5px -4px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3));
            font-size: emCalc(17px);
            color: adjust-lightness($charcoal, 20%);
            font-weight: 400;
            line-height: 1.5em;
            font-style: italic;
            text-indent: 2em;
            position: relative;
            padding: 1em;
            overflow:visible;
            &:before {
                content: "\201C";
                font-family: serif;
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 700;
                position: absolute;
                font-size: 5.5em;
                top: 15px;
                left: -50px;
                color: $blue;
                text-shadow: 7px 14px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
                display: block;
                height: 25px;
                width: 25px;
            }
        }

        footer {
            padding-top: 1em;
            cite {
                text-align: right;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                font-weight: 700;
                font-size: 1.25em;
                font-style: normal;
                color: $vblue;
                text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
                &:before {
                    content: '';
                }
            }
            &:before {
                content: '';
                position: absolute;
                border-style: solid;
                border-width: 15px 15px 0;
                border-color: #FFFFFF transparent;
                display: block;
                width: 0;
                z-index: 1;
                margin-left: -15px;
                bottom: 33px;
                left: 80%;
            }   

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Removing:

```
p {
    text-indent: 2em;
}
```

solves the issue on IE11: http://jsfiddle.net/66d25/22/

To position the quote back where you intend to place it can be achieved with:

```
p {
    text-indent: 34px; /* font-size is 17px so 2em=34px*/
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/66d25/23/

So the problem is with `em` unit and it's fine with pixels. Go figure why IE does that...

Comment: Thank you for figuring that out. I implemented the suggestion and it seemed to solve the problem with the horizontal positioning, thought the vertical positioning is still off. I'll try to replace the em units with pixels for padding and any other appropriate selectors to see if it makes a difference.